# Is there a way to deploy static sites to Netlify without Git from my android phone?

Tags: html, deployment, netlify

TL;DR - Can't use Git. Need to deploy static websites to the web. Can only use an android phone. I use Netlify on computer but dragging and dropping sites on phone doesn't work. What are my options?

I am a teacher who is teaching basic web development to kids and I have been using Netlify to help kids deploy their work to the web. It has been going well so far but after lockdown, kids are doing this remotely and a lot of my kids are poor and don't have computers at home. So they are learning to do everything on their smartphones. I've been able to find alternatives for most stuff to help them still learn it on the phone, but for site deployment using Netlify, I've found that dragging and dropping folders doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this on the phone? I would prefer to keep using Netlify, but if this doesn't work, what are my alternatives?